# Получить значение select для удаления и удалить пользователя (Thymeleaf Spring Java)

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Мой контроллер, в котором я передаю всех пользователей:

```
@GetMapping("/delete")
public String delete(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("people", personDAO.index());
    return "/people/deleteSome";
}
@DeleteMapping("/{id}/delete")
public String delete(@PathVariable("id") int id){
    personDAO.delete(id);
    return "redirect:/people";
}
```

Хочу, чтобы в полях `Select` отображались пользователи (это получилось), я выбирал определенного и удалял.

Набросал такую форму, однако не понимаю, как получить ID выбранного пользователя:

```
<form th:action="@{/people/id/delete}">
    <label for="person">Choose person:</label>
    <select id="person" >
        <option th:each="person : ${people}" th:value="${person.getId()}"
                th:text="${person.getName()}"></option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, не могу понять, как это сделать.

Comment: Вот похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590922/thymeleaf-spring-how-to-pass-to-a-controller-a-pathvariable-from-a-form-selec]) на английском стеке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Byb. Получилось сделать с помощью JQuery

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#btn').on('click', function () {
        alert($('#person').val())
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/springMvc_war_exploded/people/' + $('#person').val() + '/delete',
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function(result) {
                alert('success')
            }
        })
    });
});
```